# Tab bar icon animate into the text on android

Tags: android, tabs, android-widget, icons, android-tabhost

In my Android app i have 5 tabs in the tab bar. If i set more than 5 letters for tab name, the word starts animating if selected from right to left. I want to set a tab bar "icon" + "text", so that before i select a tab i see an icon, but if selected it animates to text. Just like it dose with long text.

`setIndicator(drawable + string)`

This is the code i have:

```
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    TabActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.social_group), "SomeText"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("SomeText"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Tab2Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("SomeText"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Tab3Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("SomeText"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab4", Tab4Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    TabActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator("SomeText"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab5", Tab5Fragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}
```

But the code wont run, and Im getting this error:

```
The method setIndicator(CharSequence, Drawable) in the type TabHost.TabSpec is not applicable for the arguments (Drawable, String)
```

Any ideas? How can i solve it?

P.S runing android 4.0.4 setting up tabs using fragments.

If i set it up like this:

```
TabActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.social_group) + "SomeText"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
```

i get "text"+"text", insted of "icon"+"text" :(

Comment: Animation of text in tab bar is its built in behaviour. AFAIK you can not control its animation. But yes you can set the Icon + Text in tab bar.

Comment: Please post your logcat error .

Comment: Hi GrIsHu, no log cat eror just red underilning under setIndicator: The method setIndicator(CharSequence, Drawable) in the type TabHost.TabSpec is not applicable for the arguments (Drawable, String). But i will try your answer and let you know if it works)))

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "Icon + Text" in Tab bar by its resource setting method as below.

> ```
>  m_spec =m_tabHost.newTabSpec("Cat").setIndicator(getString(R.string.category),
>     m_res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tabcategory)).setContent(m_mainMenuIntent);
>     m_tabHost.addTab(m_spec);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but Im getting the same result on 4.0.4. in lower versions i get an icon + text)))